# FB Like Button Disappeared (without updating webpage)

Tags: facebook

My FB Like Button Disappeared.
Nothing was changed or modified on my end.

Webpage URL: http://gregulator.com/

Any ideas?
I've spent hours trying to figure this out.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Take a look at your JavaScript console - you'll see an error there that I think is related to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Unfortunately, I was unable to identify any errors in the JavaSctipt console.

Comment: Take another look - it takes a few seconds to appear. The error is dealing with `http` vs `https` requests. Probably originating from the reference to Facebook's SDK.

Comment: Is there a known remedy?